# SVG: Dragging objects between two different SVG elements

Tags: svg, d3.js, raphael, snap.svg

I'm developing a prototype to mock this [tool](http://www.jointjs.com/rappid#a0e21d4b-a5cc-4f37-90de-3fa410e07ae9) and provide minimal functionality like

1. Drag-n-Drop simple objects
2. Connect related objects via paths
3. Generate JSON from this structure

I opted SVG and Snap.svg framework (had hard time in deciding between D3 and Snap.svg but ended up with latter just because it is latest and successor of Raphael) to implement it. I stuck with below during implementation

**Question 1:** How to drag objects between different SVG elements? Try dragging elements in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyz6hhcq/6/), objects were hidden when dragged outside of its parent  dimension. Fiddle snippet below for your perusal.

```
HTML/SVG:
<div class="stencil">
    <svg id="stencil" height="300" version="1.1" width="120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="paper">
    <div class="paper__scroller">
        <svg id="paper" height="1000" version="1.1" width="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>

Javascript:
(function(){
    var pap = Snap("#paper"),
        stencil = Snap("#stencil"),
        cir = stencil.circle(30, 50, 20),
        rec = stencil.rect(70, 33, 35, 35);
        stencilElements = stencil.group(rec, cir);

    stencilElements.attr({
        fill: "#f00",
        stroke: "#000",
        strokeWidth: 2,
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
    });

    cir.clone().drag();
    rec.clone().drag();

}());
```

**Question 2:** How to connect related objects via paths that adjust/moves accordingly when the object is dragged?

**Question 3:** How to convert the generated graph/diagram to JSON structure?

Really appreciate any reference or hints in implementing this.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't really move betwen SVGs, but any reason you have 2 ? You may be able to fiddle with 1 parent SVG and 2 inner ones or something and make it work I wonder. You could try something like graffle for connectors http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-graffle and http://code.google.com/p/x2js/ for xml/json

Comment: like Ian said. I would embed them in a parent SVG :)

Comment: @Ian thanks for the details. I would like to rephrase Question 2: Connecting related objects via paths wasn't done via program it's done  in real time by users. Basically users decide which objects to relate and draw paths between them, please share your thoughts on how to draw paths and connect related SVG objects in real time.

Comment: No reason you couldn't still use Snaps handler to click on 2 objects and then use graffle to draw a path between them (if not bothered where it connects to, you could just draw a path between the two objects centres, but I personally wouldn't reinvent the wheel, I'd go with something thats already solved the problem).